# Implementing copy and move when dropping an Item in `QTreeView`

Tags: pyqt5, drag-and-drop, drag

***I revised the whole question because the behavior I want is hard to implement and actually use.***

I'm trying to imitate the behavior in the File Explorer where when I press `Shift` while dragging, the file will be moved instead of copied.

**This is the behavior I'm trying to imitate:**
[image]

**The behavior:** is I'm using my `LeftClick` for selecting, and dragging.
[image: video of the behavior]

---

**About The behavior itself:**

I overridden the `mousePressEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent` to start the drag. When the drag is created, it uses QTimer to detect if I pressed the `Control` and `Shift` modifier. Once a modifier is detected it sets the default drop action using `setDefaultDropAction`. ***(I think I should use `setDropAction` but It's only available in the `dragMoveEvent` and I'm doing it inside the QDrag Class)***

---

**The Issues:**
Part of the behavior is working now but there is still some issues.

1. Even I press `Shift`, the DropIndicator is not changing from `+` to `->`
2. Related to the issue above, The dropAction is only `copyAction` instead of `moveAction` even I'm pressing the `Shift` key. [image: video of the issues]

---

**My Question:** What causes these issues? My gut tells me that I should've used `setDropAction` instead of `setDefaultDropAction` but again it's only available in the `dragMoveEvent`

---

**My Testing Code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class ModifiedQDrag(QDrag):
    def __init__(self, source):
        super().__init__(source)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.process_event)
        self.timer.setInterval(100)
        self.timer.start()

    def process_event(self):
        if qApp.keyboardModifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier:
            self.source().setDefaultDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)

        elif qApp.keyboardModifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier:
            print("shift pressed")
            self.source().setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)

class Tree(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.viewport().setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

    # -- mouse dragging -- #
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.dragStartPosition = event.pos()

        return super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() != Qt.RightButton:
            return
        if ((event.pos() - self.dragStartPosition).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance()):
            return
        
        drag = ModifiedQDrag(self)
        mimeData = QMimeData()
        mimeData = self.model().mimeData([self.indexAt(event.pos())])
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)

        dragAction = drag.exec(Qt.MoveAction | Qt.CopyAction, Qt.CopyAction)
        return super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        m = event.mimeData()
        if m.hasUrls():
            event.accept()
            return
    
        event.ignore()
        
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        print("[drop event] - dropped")

class FileSystemView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # -- left side -- #
        left_side_dir = r"<Dir>"

        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(left_side_dir)

        self.tree = Tree()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree.setRootIndex(self.model.index(left_side_dir))

        # -- right side -- #
        right_side_dir = r"<Dir>"

        self.model2 = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model2.setRootPath(right_side_dir)

        self.tree2 = Tree()
        self.tree2.setModel(self.model2)
        self.tree2.setRootIndex(self.model2.index(right_side_dir))
        
        # -- layout -- #
        self.tree_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.tree_layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.tree_layout.addWidget(self.tree2)

        self.setLayout(self.tree_layout)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo = FileSystemView()
demo.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The QDrag object takes control over the whole event loop for user events (similarly to modal dialogs, but more "enforced" as only drag events will be propagated unless previously accepted), so no mouse/key event will *ever* be propagated to any widget during a drag. If you want to change the drag behavior, query the `event.modifiers()` of the `dragMoveEvent()` override.

Comment: Note: `dragMoveEvent()` will *not* be triggered unless any mouse movement happens. A possibility is to create a subclass of QDrag that uses a QTimer to get the QApplication modifiers, and use it to eventually send a synthetic drag move event with the "new" default action to the current target.

Comment: @musicamante Because I'm using `ExtendedSelection` I can't really rely on keyboard modifiers as it will mess up/change the selection. My question is, is it possible to capture the normal keys such as `C` or `V`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please try to explain what is the issue you're facing and what is your exact objective. Also, you should *not* use `grabKeyboard()` when starting the drag.

Comment: @musicamante - I tried to do what you suggested, which is to create a subclass of QDrag that uses a QTimer. The only thing I'm stuck with is on how should I make it send a _drag move event with the "new" default action to the current target_.

Comment: Just to clarify, why are you using the right button? Is it still because you have issues with the selection? If that's the case, please explain those issues, as using the right button for drag is uncommon (and against the common convention of almost *any* drag/selection UI).

Comment: I'm using the right button because I want to separate the selection from the dragging so in case I need to use `MultiSelection` as SelectionMode [like this](https://i.imgur.com/H6mZFgd.gif).

Comment: The common convention is to  change selection behaviors with modifiers. This is important, especially if you eventually want to implement the context menu, which is *always* triggered by the right mouse *press* (not release). Btw, note that the "drop indicator" is the line/rectangle shown on or around a target item during drag operations (to show where the item will be dropped), what you mean is called "drag cursor".

Comment: Thanks for the really helpful info! I'm already planning on creating a context menu for deleting files and creating folders, this will definitely help me make the implementation easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt can only react to mouse movements in order to trigger changes in the drop action: as the name suggests, `dragMoveEvent()` can only be called by a mouse *move*.

Considering that, a possible solution is to manually force the mouse movement whenever the keyboard modifiers change. In this way you don't even need to create a QDrag subclass and you can keep the default behavior.

Be aware that to properly get modifiers, you should not use `keyboardModifiers()`, but [`queryKeyboardModifiers()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#queryKeyboardModifiers), as the first is only reliable when keyboard events are directly handled and might not be updated with the actual current state of the keyboard.

```py
class Tree(QTreeView):
    # ...
    def checkDrag(self):
        modifiers = qApp.queryKeyboardModifiers()
        if self.modifiers != modifiers:
            self.modifiers = modifiers
            pos = QCursor.pos()
            # slightly move the mouse to trigger dragMoveEvent
            QCursor.setPos(pos + QPoint(1, 1))
            # restore the previous position
            QCursor.setPos(pos)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() != Qt.RightButton:
            return
        if ((event.pos() - self.dragStartPosition).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance()):
            return

        self.modifiers = qApp.queryKeyboardModifiers()
        # a local timer, it will be deleted when the function returns
        dragTimer = QTimer(interval=100, timeout=self.checkDrag)
        dragTimer.start()
        self.startDrag(Qt.MoveAction|Qt.CopyAction)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.ignore()
            return
        if qApp.queryKeyboardModifiers() & Qt.ShiftModifier:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        else:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
        event.accept()
```